# Laravel + Docker issue (changes do not apply)

Tags: php, laravel, git, docker, nginx

I have a docker container (php7.2+composer installed+laravel+git), which after my latest push , does not show or compile the new front-end code changes . Back-end changes work fine , but front-end , even after running `npm run production` does not work . Also , I have deployed the code on a machine without docker and it worked fine , but in the docker environment , it seems front-end codes do not get compiled inside the container . is there any solution ?

**Update**

I have rebuilt the container on all my cluster servers and the problem consists.

**Update**

I have removed css and js folders in public directory, but nothing changed ! It seems it is loading from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a browser cache try clicking **CTRL** + **F5** or open page in incognito mode.

Comment: I'm afraid , I have tried clearing my cache several times but noting happend

Comment: Try running docker ps and check if some old container isn't running in the background with old code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from another volume where NGINX used , I could solve the problem by changing NGINX volume dir .